# Software to do Data Mining in SQL Server 2022

Tags: gratis, sql-server

I'm tasked with creating a few data mining models for the Adventure Works demo database. I'm supposed to have been using SSDT and Visual Studio with SQL Server, however the latest version of SSDT (2022) has removed data mining completely.

Why did they discontinue the support for this feature in the first place?

What tool am I supposed to use now in its place? I need a tool that could integrate with the SSDT VS projects, but the documentation doesn't suggest an alternative, I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

[Data Mining Wizard (Analysis Services - Data Mining)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/data-mining/data-mining-wizard-analysis-services-data-mining?view=asallproducts-allversions) is only available on SQL Server 2019 and earlier Analysis Services.

> Data mining was deprecated in SQL Server 2017 Analysis Services and
> now discontinued in SQL Server 2022 Analysis Services. Documentation
> is not updated for deprecated and discontinued features. To learn
> more, see Analysis Services backward compatibility.

Alternatives are:

- [Data Mining (SSAS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/data-mining/data-mining-ssas?view=asallproducts-allversions)
- [Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-au/)

Comment: yeah, I know they discontinued its support, it's even mentioned in my question. Power BI looks promising.